# How to set signingConfig for different flavor dimensions?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to figure out how can I specify a `signingConfig` for the individual flavor dimensions generated. I have seen how to do it when using different flavor but not flavor dimensions.

I'm currently applying a different package name for the different flavor dimensions successfully and thought maybe something similar could be done with `signingConfig`?

```
> android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
>     def flavorString = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getFlavorName()
>     def mergedFlavour = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getMergedFlavor();
> 
>     if(flavorString.equalsIgnoreCase("amazonFree")) {
>         mergedFlavour.setApplicationId("com.test.amazon.free")
>     }
>     if(flavorString.equalsIgnoreCase("amazonPro")) {
>         mergedFlavour.setApplicationId("com.test.amazon.pro")
>     }
>     if(flavorString.equalsIgnoreCase("googleFree")) {
>         mergedFlavour.setApplicationId("com.test.google.free")
>     }
>     if(flavorString.equalsIgnoreCase("googlePro")) {
>         mergedFlavour.setApplicationId("com.test.google.pro")
>     } }
```

**My flavor setup**

> ```
> // Special flavor dimensions for different markets and
> // versions paid and free.
> flavorDimensions 'market', 'version'
>
> productFlavors {
>     amazon {
>         flavorDimension 'market'
>     }
>     google {
>         flavorDimension 'market'
>     }
>     // Base free version
>     free {
>         flavorDimension 'version'
>         // Need this cause of all the ad libraries we are using :/
>         defaultConfig.multiDexEnabled true
>
>         // For now we sign all free versions with this config
>         // cause we have no idea how to sign the individual flavor dimensions.
>         signingConfig signingConfigs.googleFree
>     }
>     // Base pro version
>     pro {
>         flavorDimension 'version'
>
>         // For now we sign all free versions with this config
>         // cause we have no idea how to sign the individual flavor dimensions.
>         signingConfig signingConfigs.googlePro
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: ran into the same issue, did you ever get this done?

Answer (score 2):

When you start using `flavorDimensions` the best solution to set `signingConfig` for different variants is to use `androidComponents` block. For example:

```
androidComponents {
        onVariants(selector().all(), { variant ->
            if (variant.name == "xxyyzzGmsRelease") {
                variant.signingConfig?.setConfig(signingConfigs.play_store)
            } else if (variant.name == "xxyyzzHmsRelease") {
                variant.signingConfig?.setConfig(signingConfigs.huawei_store)
            }
        })
    }
```

Tested on **Gradle 7.4** and **AGP 7.3.1**.

Answer (score 1):

First of all applicationId can be applied in `productFlavors` block itself:

```
productFlavors {
    amazonFree {
        applicationId 'com.test.amazon.free'
    }
    amazonPro {
        applicationId 'com.test.amazon.pro'
    }
    googleFree {
        applicationId 'com.test.google.free'
    }
    googlePro {
        applicationId 'com.test.google.pro'
    }
}
```

Signing config can be configured per flavor the same way:

```
productFlavors {
    amazonFree {
        applicationId 'com.test.amazon.free'
        signingConfig  signingConfigs.amazonFree
    }
    amazonPro {
        applicationId 'com.test.amazon.pro'
        signingConfig  signingConfigs.amazonPro
    }
    googleFree {
        applicationId 'com.test.google.free'
        signingConfig  signingConfigs.googleFree
    }
    googlePro {
        applicationId 'com.test.google.pro'
        signingConfig  signingConfigs.googlePro
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer but I knew how to do this already. The problem is when you start using flavor DIMENSIONS. Things get a bit more complicated.

Comment: Sorry for that. What flavor dimensions are you using? Can you provide flavors configuration?

Comment: I have updated my question to include my flavor config.

Comment: How do we do it for kotlin DSL?