# Build Configurations based on App Variant (BuildType + Flavor)

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to set `signingConfig`, `manifestPlaceholders`, `buildConfigField` for Application variant. I can set them for each buildType **or!** productFlavor independently, but what i need is to set them based on both productFlavor **and!** buildType.

```
buildTypes{
  getByName("debug"){}
  getByName("release"){}
  create("staging"){}
}

productFlavors {
  create("global"){}
  create("local"){}
}
```

On the above example, there are 3 different buildTypes and 2 different productFlavors. That means 6 total APK variants. For each of this APK (*globalRelease, globalStaging, globalDebug, localRelease, localStaging, localDebug*), i want to use different signingConfig for example. How do i set it?

Tried:

- If i set it in buildType, then there will be only 3 different signingConfigs
- If i set it in flavor, then there will be only 2 different signingConfigs
- If i try to set it in `applicationVariants.all{}`, there is no setter functions, only getters on Variant object ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22511486/3736955))
- setting fields on `(variant.mergedFlavor as DefaultProductFlavor)` does not add buildConfigField values to BuildConfig.java ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60103604/3736955))

Comment: Unanswered similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742184/multiple-signingconfigs-for-multiple-variants?rq=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### After Gradle 8.x

---

> Error: "Build Type contains custom BuildConfig fields, but the feature is disabled"

[Need to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74634321/fixing-the-build-type-contains-custom-buildconfig-fields-but-the-feature-is-di) enable `buildConfig` for `variant.buildConfigFields.set()`, it's default value [was](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-8-0-0-release-notes) `true` but now is `false`:

```kotlin
android {
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }
}
```

> Error: "Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl ...
> Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build
> file"

`namespace` is [required](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-8-0-0-release-notes) in module level build scripts now. You need to specify it for **each** module **separately**, and it should be [same as](https://developer.android.com/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace) **package name** of that module (not appId).

This is also related to generated `R` class, it will become `my.module.package.R`. Another breaking change is you can't use `this.module.package.R` for referring resources *(drawable, string...)* of another module you depend on, you have to use `my.another.module.R.drawable.login`. Because [previously](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-8-0-0-release-notes#default-changes) default value of `android.nonTransitiveRClass` flag was `false` and `R` included drawables of every module you depend on. Now its default value is `true`, so `R` only contains resources of that module *([improves](https://developer.android.com/build/optimize-your-build) build time).*

Additionally you need to remove `package=""` from AndroidManifest.xml of each module.

#### After Gradle 7.x

---

Instead of `applicationVariants.all{}`, [we now use](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/variant/AndroidComponentsExtension) `androidComponents { onVariants{ .. }}` outside `android{}` block. This code should work on Gradle 7.0.2 and AGP 7.0.1:

```
androidComponents {
    onVariants { variant ->
        variant.buildConfigFields.put("MY_CUSTOM_FIELD", BuildConfigField("String", "MyCustomValue", null))
        variant.manifestPlaceholders.put("MY_MANIFEST_FIELD", "MyManifestValue")
    }
}
```

On AGP 7.0.x, there [is no way to set](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197430188) `signingConfig` for `mergedFlavor` (buildType+flavor). You can set for buildType or flavor individually, but not for combination.

On AGP 7.1.x, you can do it. But it requires AGP 7.1.0-alpha10, Gradle 7.2-rc-3, AndroidStudio BumbleBee 2021.1.1 alpha10:

```
androidComponents {
    onVariants { variant ->
        variant.signingConfig?.setConfig(android.signingConfigs.getByName("buildTypeXFlavorA"))
    }
}
```

‎‎
‎

#### Before Gradle 7.x

---

To make changes on different variants (buildType+productFlavor), i had to use `android.applicationVariants.all{}`. But different paths used to achieve multiple `signingConfig`, `manifestPlaceholders`, `buildConfigField`

**1) manifestPlaceholders**

```kotlin
applicationVariants.all{
    val variant = this
}
```

There is no getter/setter for `manifestPlaceholders` on `variant` object. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60103604/3736955), we can make `variant.mergedFlavor` mutable. Setting `manifestPlaceholders` on `variant.mergedFlavor` did work.

```kotlin
import com.android.builder.core.DefaultProductFlavor

applicationVariants.all{
    val manifestPlaceholders: Map<String, String>
    val variant = this
    val mutableMergedFlavor = variant.mergedFlavor as DefaultProductFlavor
    mutableMergedFlavor.addManifestPlaceholders(manifestPlaceholders)
}
```

**2) buildConfigField**

Using the same approach, calling `addBuildConfigField(ClassFieldImpl(type, name, value))` on `mutableMergedFlavor` did not work. But [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30486355/3736955), it can be set directly on `variant`.

```kotlin
import com.android.builder.internal.ClassFieldImpl

applicationVariants.all{
    val buildConfigFields: List<ClassFieldImpl>
    val variant = this
    buildConfigFields.forEach { 
        variant.buildConfigField(it.type, it.name, it.value) 
    }
}
```

**3) signingConfig**
`signingConfig` can be set on `mutableMergedFlavor` shown above, except on `debug` variants. All `debug` variants use default signing options, even if you set it on `variant.mergedFlavor`. But if you set [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222229/debug-signing-config-on-gradle-product-flavors/30182112#comment54839933_30182112) as null, then you can override it as well.

```kotlin
import com.android.builder.core.DefaultProductFlavor

signingConfigs {
    create("myDebug") {}
}
buildTypes {
    getByName("debug") {
        signingConfig = null // to override
    }
}
applicationVariants.all{
    val variant = this
    val mutableMergedFlavor = variant.mergedFlavor as DefaultProductFlavor
    mutableMergedFlavor.signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("myDebug")
}
```

**To put all together:**

```kotlin
import com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant
import com.android.builder.internal.ClassFieldImpl
import com.android.builder.model.SigningConfig
import com.android.builder.core.DefaultProductFlavor
import java.util.*

fun configureVariant(variant: ApplicationVariant,
                     signingConfig: SigningConfig,
                     buildConfigFields: List<ClassFieldImpl>,
                     manifestPlaceholders: Map<String, String>) {

    println("configureVariant: ${variant.name}")
    buildConfigFields.forEach {
        variant.buildConfigField(it.type, it.name, it.value)
    }

    val mutableMergedFlavor = variant.mergedFlavor as DefaultProductFlavor
    mutableMergedFlavor.signingConfig = signingConfig
    mutableMergedFlavor.addManifestPlaceholders(manifestPlaceholders)
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        create("myDebug") {}
        create("myRelease") {}
    }

    flavorDimensions("region")
    productFlavors {
        create("global") {
            setDimension("region")
            setApplicationId("")
        }
        create("local") {
            setDimension("region")
            setApplicationId("")
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("debug") {
            signingConfig = null
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all {
        val variant = this
        when {
            variant.name.equals("localDebug", true) -> {
                configureVariant(
                        variant,
                        signingConfigs.getByName("localDebug"),
                        listOf(ClassFieldImpl("String", "NAME", "\"VALUE\"")),
                        mapOf("KEY" to "VALUE")
                )
            }
            variant.name.equals("globalStaging", true) -> {
                configureVariant(
                        variant,
                        signingConfigs.getByName("globalStaging"),
                        listOf(ClassFieldImpl("String", "NAME", "\"VALUE2\"")),
                        mapOf("KEY" to "VALUE2")
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After Android Studio 4.0.0 (gradle 6.1.1), `DefaultProductFlavor` can not be resolved. `AbstractProductFlavor` can be used as workaround

Comment: `signingConfig` part does not work on gradle 7

Comment: On Gradle 7.4 and AGP 7.3.1 we can use another approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74574617/5068914