# Sign variants with different signingConfig - AGP 7.4.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin-7.4

I have multiple `flavourDimensions`. I try to sign each resulting variant with a different `signingConfig`. I'm currently using Gradle 7.5.1 and Android Gradle Plugin 7.4.1.

I've followed the suggested approach from both [Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197430188) and this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60992857/1827254), as the way to set a custom signingConfig to a variant has changed since AGP 7.1.

Approach:

```
androidComponents {
    onVariants { variant ->
        variant.signingConfig?.setConfig(android.signingConfigs.getByName("buildTypeXFlavorA"))
    }
}
```

However, when either doing `Build > Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) > Build APK(s)` or `./gradlew assemble<variant name>Release` I end up with an `unsigned` APK (`<apk name>-unsigned.apk`)

Does anyone has the same issue? How can I get the signed APK?

Here is a example of the current configuration:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {

        appleRedRelease {
            storeFile file("/path_to_file")
            keyAlias "the_alias"
            storePassword "the_password"
            keyPassword "the_key_password"
        }
        pearYellowRelease {
            //...
        }
        //...
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            //...
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "fruit", "color", "version"

    productFlavors {

        apple {
            dimension "fruit"
        }
        pear {
            dimension "fruit"
        }

        red {
            dimension "color"
        }
        yellow {
            dimension "color"
        }

        free {
            dimension "version"
        }
        paid {
            dimension "version"
        }
    }
}

androidComponents {
    onVariants(selector().all(), { variant ->
        if (variant.name == "appleRedFreeRelease") {
            variant.signingConfig.setConfig(android.signingConfigs.appleRedRelease)
        } else {
            //...
        }
    })
}
```